# Understanding usage of OpenJDK vs Oracle JDK

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to get my head around the personal and commercial usages of oracle jdk vs open jdk and need validation and inputs on my understanding.

OpenJDK: Free for personal and commercial use.

Oracle JDK: Free for personal, paid for commercial.

From an organization's perspective, it will be cost-sensible to go for a free version using open jdk rather than shell out money on licenses. So why ever opt for an oracle jdk? What's the trick here?

One possibility I can think of is support. Open JDK has no long term support, has a new version release every 6 months, so if my application is running on Open JDK 8, after 6 months with the new jdk being made available, there are chances of my application to stop working?
If yes, that leaves me with the following options.

1. I would need to either migrate to the newer open JDK version.
2. Had I been using oracle JDK all along I had the guarantee from Oracle that my app still works even after whatever new releases.

Since up-time of products is crucial to the organization, folks don't mind shelling out on oracle jdk licenses than landing up in a situation where you saved bucks but on one fine day your processes stop working.

Is my understanding correct, and if not what all am I missing?

Yet another perspective I have in mind is how is the release of new open jdk version going to stop my applications from working, my app is still running on previous version of openjdk which is perfectly compatible - but yes I might not be able to leverage the new features released in the jdk if I do not migrate.

Thoughts?

Comment: "*Open JDK has no long term support*" - This is not entirely true. The LTS will receive only six month public support from Oracle. After this time, it is up to the OpenJDK community to provide public support. There is, however, no guaranteed support, that is true.

Comment: There are business that provide commercial support for OpenJDK. In the end, cost of licensing is not really the issue here -- the important question is what kind of support do you want, and from whom? This is a commercial matter, really, rather than a technical one.

Comment: Your apps won't just "stop working" on OpenJDK 8 after some period of time.  But eventually, the community will focus its maintenance efforts exclusively on newer versions of OpenJDK and OpenJDK 8 will no longer receive any of the bug fixes or security updates that would be present in the newer versions.

Comment: “…the release of new open jdk version going to stop my applications from working” It is *very unlikely* that your application will stop working.  Java goes to great lengths to preserve backward compatibility.  If you avoid using illicit hacks (like using undocumented Java SE classes, or forcing private fields in Java SE classes to be accessible), and avoid shoddy libraries that use such hacks, your application almost certainly will work in all future versions of Java.  I have never had an application stop working in a subsequent release of Java.